# Checkbox in HTML turns off a function in a .js file

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I am looking to make a checkbox that when unchecked, will turn off a certain function in a .js file. Can someone help me?

popup.html
HTML Check box:

content.js
Turn off this function:
    var tweet = new Array();
    var tweetName = new Array();

```
function linkSnipe() {

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    tweetName[i] = document.getElementsByClassName("fullname js-action-profile-name show-popup-with-id")[0].innerHTML;
    tweet[i] = document.getElementsByClassName("js-tweet-text")[i].innerHTML;
  }


  if (tweet[0].match(shoeName) == shoeName && tweet[0].match(filterer) != filterer && tweet[0].match(filter2) != filter2) {
    if(checkon == "Tweets"){
      document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-timeline-link")[0].click();
      update();
    }
  } 

  else if (tweet[1].match(shoeName) == shoeName && tweet[1].match(filterer) != filterer  && tweet[1].match(filter2) != filter2) {
    if(checkon == "Tweets"){
      document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-timeline-link")[1].click();
      update();
    }
  }

  else if (tweet[2].match(shoeName) == shoeName && tweet[2].match(filterer) != filterer && tweet[2].match(filter2) != filter2) {
    if(checkon == "Tweets"){
      document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-timeline-link")[2].click();
      update();
    }
  }

  else if (tweet[3].match(shoeName) == shoeName && tweet[3].match(filterer) != filterer && tweet[3].match(filter2) != filter2) {
    if(checkon == "Tweets"){
      document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-timeline-link")[3].click();
      update();
    }
  }

  else if (tweet[4].match(shoeName) == shoeName && tweet[4].match(filterer) != filterer && tweet[4].match(filter2) != filter2) {
    if(checkon == "Tweets"){
      document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-timeline-link")[4].click();
      update();
    }
  }
  else if(checkon == "Tweets") {
    location.reload();
  }
}
setTimeout("linkSnipe()", 250);    
 }
```

Comment: You could also store the variable in chrome and call the variable when running your function.

Answer (score 1):

When the checkbox is checked, redefine the function as:

```
<input type=checkbox ..... onchange="doit()">

function doit() {
  window.linkSnipe=function() {}
}
```

I've used this too:

```
function doit() {
  window['linkSnipe']=function() {}
}
```

If you want to turn the function on and off by the checkbox:

```
<input type=checkbox ..... onchange="doit(this)">

var linkSnipeSave = linkSnipe;

function doit(ck) {
  if (ck.checked)
    window['linkSnipe']=linkSnipeSave 
  else {
    linkSnipeSave = linkSnipe;          //not sure if this line is needed...pls test
    window['linkSnipe']=function() {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply have a Boolean variable that changes with the state of your check box. You could then put an if statement around the function call that will only trigger if the checkbox is checked.

http://jsfiddle.net/W5P8X/

```
//initialize some variables.
bike_checked = false;
car_checked = false;

//get elements by their ID from html
bike = document.getElementById("bike");
car = document.getElementById("car");

//add event listeners to the html elements we found above
bike.addEventListener("click", toggle_bike, false);
car.addEventListener("click", toggle_car, false);

//toggle bike_checked variable on click
function toggle_bike(){
    if(bike_checked == true)
        bike_checked = false;
    else
        bike_checked=true;
    current_state();
}

//toggle car_checked variable on click
function toggle_car(){
    if(car_checked == true)
        car_checked = false;
    else
        car_checked=true;

    current_state();
}

//output current state.
function current_state(){
    if(car_checked == true)
        alert('Car checked');

    if(bike_checked == true)
        alert('Bike checked');
}
```

I answered with only javascript and no jQuery, but you could probably make it a bit more concise with jQuery.

I hope this helps.